# Use high precision to convert image from one EPSG defined CRS to another

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, image, epsg

This question is based on [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/348740/148791): I'm converting multiple images (.jpg or .png) from one EPSG defined CRS system to another, e.g. from [EPSG:31255](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31255) to [EPSG:25833](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833) (on a server within a Java app).

Currently I'm using this code (GeoTools 22.2, Java 8):

```
//codeIn file (already includes TOWGS84): http://epsg.io/31255.wkt
String codeOut = "epsg:25833";

public void convert(String pathIn, String pathOut, String codeOut) {
    File fileIn = new File(pathIn);

    if(fileIn.exists() && fileIn.isFile()) {
        try {
            File fileOut = new File(pathOut);
            CoordinateReferenceSystem crsOut = CRS.decode(codeOut);
            AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(fileIn);
            Hints hints = null;

            AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(fileIn, hints);
            GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null);
            reader.dispose();

            GridCoverage2D coverageTransf = (GridCoverage2D) Operations.DEFAULT.resample(coverage, crsOut);
            GeoTiffFormat outFormat = new GeoTiffFormat();
            GridCoverageWriter writer = outFormat.getWriter(fileOut, hints);
            writer.write(coverageTransf, null);
            writer.dispose();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add high precision to it. In Proj4 I'd use this command:

```
+ellps=bessel +nadgrids=GIS_GRID.gsb +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13d20 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000 +units=m +no_defs +geoidgrids=foo.gtx +to +datum=WGS84 +proj=utm +zone=33 +no_defs
```

In [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/278335/148791) similar question there's a [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#add-grid-shift-transform-files) to a website that tells you to copy the two files (.gsb and .gtx) to the `user_projections` folder, which of course doesn't exist in my app.

My guess is that I'll have to give `GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null)` some type of `GeneralParameterValue[]`. Is this the right way to do it and if so, how exactly do I give it the path of the two files and/or the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by creating a `src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift/` folder (it will get rolled up into your jar when you do a `mvn install`) to drop the `GIS_GRID.gsb` file into.

You can use some code like this to check the transform is being picked up:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem epsg31255 = CRS.decode("epsg:31255");
System.out.println(epsg31255);
System.out.println();
transform = CRS.findMathTransform(CRS.decode("epsg:25833"), epsg31255);
System.out.println(transform);
```

Currently, this gives me this transform:

```
CONCAT_MT[INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
      PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
      PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356], 
      PARAMETER["central_meridian", 15.0], 
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
      PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
      PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
      PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]], 
  PARAM_MT["Ellipsoid_To_Geocentric", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356]], 
  PARAM_MT["Coordinate Frame Rotation (geog2D domain)", 
    PARAMETER["dx", -601.7055480109889], 
    PARAMETER["dy", -84.2586089323459], 
    PARAMETER["dz", -485.2300592613099], 
    PARAMETER["ex", 4.73539999802488], 
    PARAMETER["ey", 1.3144999994517264], 
    PARAMETER["ez", 5.392999997750596], 
    PARAMETER["ppm", 2.3878715100789094]], 
  PARAM_MT["Geocentric_To_Ellipsoid", 
    PARAMETER["dim", 2], 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6377397.155], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356078.962818189]], 
  PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6377397.155], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356078.962818189], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", 13.333333333333336], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", -5000000.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

## Update

I can confirm that dropping the `AT_GIS_GRID.gsb` I downloaded from http://www.bev.gv.at/portal/page?_pageid=713,2157075&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL into a directory called `src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift/` causes the above code to give me this transform:

```
CONCAT_MT[INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
      PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
      PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314140356], 
      PARAMETER["central_meridian", 15.0], 
      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
      PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
      PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
      PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]], 
  INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["NTv2", 
      PARAMETER["Latitude and longitude difference file", "AT_GIS_GRID.gsb"]]], 
  PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
    PARAMETER["semi_major", 6377397.155], 
    PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356078.962818189], 
    PARAMETER["central_meridian", 13.333333333333336], 
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["false_northing", -5000000.0]], 
  PARAM_MT["Affine", 
    PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
    PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 0.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_0_1", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_0", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["elt_1_1", 0.0]]]
```

I found the link to the transform page from the [Proj documentation](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/tree/master/europe#proj-datumgrid-europe).

Comment: Is it possible to read the gsb file at runtime, so I can change it without exporting the jar again? What about the .gtx file and how do I use the remaining parameters in the command (e.g. the -5 mio. one) on that image?

Comment: It may be, GeoServer manages it - there is probably Spring magic involved. You can add a new projection string (again see the GeoServer docs for details)

Comment: So is this more of a GeoServer problem than a GeoTools one and the latter doesn't really support adding these files at runtime, right? Is there anything I have to add to my code - there isn't too much more to it than what I posted in my question - to make it use the .gsb and .gtx file? Something like a certain call to a function to tell it to use it or does everything happen automatically (as with the .prj and wld. files) as long as the files are in the folder you mentioned?

Comment: GeoTools is the underlying lib of GeoServer (which has more users and docs) - all you should need to do is drop the files into the folder I said - then the referencing engine will pick them up

Comment: Do I have to use a specific name? I copied the files into that folder, renamed them to "foo.gsb" and "foo.gtx" and ran your test code but the resulting transform didn't mention any of the files, so they probably weren't used. Even if they were used, how does GeoServer know what part of EPSG:25833 they should be used on without giving it the additional information of the command I posted in the question?

Comment: Normally there is an expected name e.g. for GB where I live it is called `OSTN02_NTv2.gsb` and I've never tried to change it's name

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/tree/master/europe#proj-datumgrid-europe seems to indicate it should be called `AT_GIS_GRID.gsb` available from http://www.bev.gv.at/portal/page?_pageid=713,2157075&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Did you download [this](http://www.bev.gv.at/portal/page?_pageid=713,2601276&_dad=portal&_schema=PORTAL) file (3119kb)? Cleaning the project only gave me the first transform you posted but after a restart I'm now getting the one with `INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["NTv2", PARAMETER["Latitude and longitude difference file", "AT_GIS_GRID.gsb"]]]`, thanks! I was just told that the .gtx file and the rest of the command aren't actually needed as it's unambiguous with the used epsg code and gsb file anyway. So thanks again for your help!

Comment: I've got one more question: Is it possible to generate the new world file for the new image (that used the gsb file) automatically?

Comment: You can write out using the gt-image module but world files are a bit of a hack - geotiffs are much safer and easier to use

Comment: My app needs to be able to use jpg/png, so I'm currently "stuck" with wld files. I checked the [image plugin](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/image.html) page and the [image tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html) and while they contain good information, there isn't any about how to generate the world file. There's mention of `envelope` [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Writing-world-files-TFW-td4324272.html) but it's from 2009. Could you please point me in the right direction where I can find the function to use?

Comment: When in doubt with GeoTools check the tests - https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/image/src/test/java/org/geotools/gce/image/WorldImageWriterTest.java#L111 should get you going